# How can I set a cronjob to run every 15 minutes between 6.30am and 9.45pm

Tags: cron

This job should run on all days of the week except Saturday and Sunday.

On each day, the job should run initially at 06:30, and every 15 minutes thereafter, until the final execution of the job, at 21:45.

```
30,45 6 * * 1-5 /path/to/script

*/15 7-20 * * 1-5 /path/to/script

0,15,30,45 21 * * 1-5 /path/to/script
```

This job seems to be continuing in 15-minute iterations beyond 21:45; running at 10:00, 10:15 and so on.

Comment: *"This job seems to be running beyond 21:45"* Crontab only fires off your script, but is not responsible for its execution time. Hence it may run after 21:45:00 if it would take more than 1 second to run.

Comment: Doh. I think I see the problem. Ubuntu's timezone is set to EST and I'm in the UK. Time for bed.

Comment: "Doh" be specific then. Get a good night's rest ;)

Comment: If this is a server and not your personal computer, it should be running in UTC. http://yellerapp.com/posts/2015-01-12-the-worst-server-setup-you-can-make.html

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions.

Comment: I'll let myself out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Ubuntu's timezone was set to EST, rather than the UTC time standard by which I am working. Hence, though I thought it was 10pm, it was in fact, from the perspective of cron, 5pm.

I changed the timezone, as per an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3375/how-to-change-time-zone-settings-from-the-command-line), using the following command:

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone UTC
```